# Set of Arraylists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, set

```
    Set<ArrayList<Integer>> hs = new HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    arr.add(1);
    arr.add(2);
    arr.add(3);
    arr.add(4);

    hs.add(arr);

    ArrayList<Integer> arr1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    arr1.add(4);
    arr1.add(3);
    arr1.add(2);
    arr1.add(1);

    hs.add(arr1);

    System.out.println(hs.size());
```

The output I get is 2. I want to get 1 as both the arrayLists have the same elements. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's a typo. You're adding to `arr` instead of `arr1`.

Comment: I have fixed the typo and changed the order of the elements. I am still getting 2. However, if elements have same order then it gives 1. But i need it to work for any order.

Comment: Now you're asking a separate question. Lists are ordered by definition. If you need an unordered comparison, use a set.

Comment: i need unordered with duplicates allowed. Set does not allow duplicates

Comment: Maybe take a look at Guava's [`Multiset`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multiset).

Answer (score 3):

In the second block, after creating `arr1`, you add the number 1 to 3 to arr **again**. Obviously, an `ArrayList` with 8 elements isn't equal to an empty `ArrayList`, so you'd have two members in the `HashSet`. If you fix the code to add the same elements to `arr1`, you'll get a `HashSet` with a size of 1.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you pasted, you are adding 1, 2, 3, and 4 to the first list (`arr`) twice, and adding nothing to the second list (`arr1`). Thus `arr1.equals(arr)` is going to be false.

Fix the typo in your code so that `arr1` contains the same elements as `arr`, and you will achieve your goal.

Answer (score -4):

Even if the contents are same, both arraylists are different objects. You are bound to see 2 elements in the set.

Its like having two employees with exactly the same name.

Not sure if you can implement equals method for arraylists.

Comment: This is not correct; `ArrayList.equals()` and `ArrayList.hashCode()` are calculated based on the elements in the list, not the object instance.